# ROC trainable WEKA segmentation

Tags: weka, image-segmentation, roc

I am a basic user of trainable weka segmention plug in from Fiji. I would like to know how the ROC curve evaluates the performance of a fastrandomforest classifier? As I have several points in the curve, conceptually, each one represents how each pixel was evaluated? does it asses the probability assigned to each pixel? Or the probability assigned to each pixel is irrelevant for the ROC curve?
Grtz!
Natalia

Answer (score 0):

The [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) provided by the Trainable Weka Segmentation plugin is calculated using all the training samples, that is, the pixels traced by the user as belonging to the different classes. As any other ROC curve, it displays the true positive rate (TPR) vs the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold values. Using only training samples and a Random Forest classifier without pruning, the curve is not very informative because the classifier learns the training set by heart and therefore the curve will be of area 1.